# How should I manage profiles properties in multi module spring boot project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In fact, I have 2 modules in my spring project: **APP** and **TEST**.

---

At **APP** module I have 3 property files:

1. application.yml
2. application-prop1.yml
3. application-prop2.yml

application.yml contains property inside (spring.profiles.include= prop1, prop2)

---

At **TEST** module I have 1 application-main-test.yml and annotated test class with

@SpringBootTest(
properties = {"spring.profiles.active=main-test"}
)

---

So, when I execute my Test classes in **TEST** module Spring context contains all 4 profiles: main, prop1, prop2, main-test instead of main-test only

---

When I was changed name of application.yml file in **APP** module to application.deploy.yml Spring context starts to contain only @main-test profile what exactly I want to have.

I would be appreciate to someone who can explain me the mechanism of how I can exclude all profiles from **APP** module without renaming

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```java
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:main-test.yml")
public class RunIntegrationTests {


}
```

Comment: Hi, @Dilermando. Big thanks for reply. In fact, @SpringBootTest( properties = {"spring.profiles.active=main-test"} ) has the same effect.